# How can I get correct autocompletion for ambiguous file extensions?

Tags: ide, syntax-highlighting, filetype

I'm editing Prolog files as part of an exploratory project, and some of the files I'm working with have the extension `.pl`, which is shared by Perl files. Whenever I do work on a Prolog file named `[somefile].pl`, Vim gives me syntax highlighting and error detection for Perl, rather than Prolog. I could totally disable syntax highlighting for Perl or force `.pl` to be recognized as Prolog, but I'd like to know if there's a less dictatorial way of fixing the issue. Is there a way I can set the syntax highlighting programmatically, or use some sort of a key combination to tell Vim that I'm editing a Prolog file rather than a Perl file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only answer the second part of your question.
You can tell Vim that you're editing a Prolog file with this command:

```
:set syntax=prolog
```

If you never work in Perl, then it wouldn't seem "dictatorial" to add custom configuration in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl setfiletype prolog syntax=prolog
```

Comment: And you could map `:set syntax=prolog` to something (maybe `<Leader>-p`).

Answer (score 5):

You could add the following to the top or the bottom of the file.

```
%vim: ft=prolog
```

This will tell Vim to treat the file as a Prolog file.

See [“Modelines” in the user manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6) and [`:help modeline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline).